# Rotate list of lines

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, cursor-movement, register

Assume you have the following block of text (yes: I am using vim-latex, but this is not relevant):

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item 1
 % [[[
 \item 2
 \item 3
 \item 4
 \item 5
 % ]]]
 \item 6
\end{itemize}
```

My aim is to transform it in the following block of text:

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item 1
 % [[[
 \item 3
 \item 4
 \item 5
 \item 2
 % ]]]
 \item 6
\end{itemize}
```

i.e. the first line of the block between the markers should become the last line of said block (markers are inessential: you can change them, if you like).

Clearly a cut-and-paste of one line would do it, but I would like to have a sequence of commands to achieve this in order to save them in a register, so that I can execute it automatically within a block, irrespective of the number of `\item` lines.

In the most general case, ideally each `\item` should be considered of variable dimension: the goal is to take the first `\item` of the block within the markers with all the lines up to the following `\item` and move them in the last position of the block.

As an intermediate problem between the *"all `\item` are one line"* and *"complete generality"*, you can consider the case *"all `\item` have fixed length (say x lines)"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
?% \[\[\[?+1
dd
/% ]]]/-1
p
```

- `?% \[\[\[?+1` move to the beginning of the block (the line after the `% [[[` marker)
- `dd` cut the line
- `/% ]]]/-1` move to the end of the block (the line before the `% ]]]` marker)
- `p` Paste the cut line

Or for the more complex one:

```
?% \[\[\[?+1
$
d/\\item/-1
/% ]]]/-1
p
```

- `?% \[\[\[?+1` move to the beginning of the block (the line after the `% [[[` marker)
- `$` move to the end of the line
- `d/\\item/-1` cut the lines to the next item (in line mode)
- `/% ]]]/-1` move to the end of the block (the line before the `% ]]]` marker)
- `p` Paste the cut line

Comment: This looks quite close to what I am looking for. Two points: 1) in my test, the command `/% ]]] +/-1` doesn't work, while the command `/% ]]]/-1` does what you say. 2) If I do it on the file, with the change I said it works, but if I save it on a register in my .vimrc, then it doesn't. Clearly, I am saving it in a wrong way. How do I save it correctly?

Comment: Sorry for the misstyping :-|. I have corrected the answer. This one should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to your question:

1. somehow select a "block" of variable length between two "markers",
2. make the first line of the block the last.

This answer addresses the latter part.

Moving a given line after another given line is the job of `:help :move`:

```
:<fromline>m<toline>
```

If you have selected the lines to rotate, the most canonical approach would be to move the first line of the selection (`:help '<`) below the last line of the selection (`:help '>`):

```
:<C-u>'<m'>
```

which you can map to whatever works for you:

```
xnoremap <F5> :<C-u>'<m'><CR>
```

Comment: This solution requires me to select lines: it is not what I was looking for. What I am looking for is: a sequence of commands to be saved in a register (say `@r`)  such that if the cursor is on the very first line, then hitting `@r` does the job

Answer (score 1):

The simple version would be:

```
function! s:Rotate(fline, lline, ...) abort
  " Optional count extraction
  let nb = 1
  if a:0 > 0
    if a:1 =~ '\v^\d+$'
      let nb = a:1
    endif
  endif
  " The lines to rotate
  let lines = getline(a:fline, a:lline)
  " The rotation
  let updated_lines = lines[nb :] + lines[: (nb-1)]
  " The update
  call setline(a:fline, updated_lines)
endfunction

command! -range -nargs=* Rotate call s:Rotate(<line1>, <line2>, <f-args>)
```

Which could be called on a selected range with `:'<,'>Rotate [optional-count]`

At this point, we just work with single lines.

The problem is that `\item` may span on multiple lines. Let's expect an extra parameter: the leading text that tells what starts a group (I'll ignore things like embedded itemlist)

```
function! s:Rotate(fline, lline, ...) abort
  " echomsg "a:000 -> "..string(a:000)
  " The lines to rotate
  let lines = getline(a:fline, a:lline)

  " Optional count extraction
  let nb      = 1
  let pattern = ''
  if a:0 > 0 " TODO: simplify! Fix?
    if a:1 =~ '\v^-?\d+$'
      let nb = a:1
      if a:0 > 1
        let pattern = a:2
      endif
    else
      let pattern = a:1
    endif
  endif
  if !empty(pattern)
    " Let's identify groups
    let groups = lines
          \ ->copy()
          \ ->map({n, l -> [n,l]})
          \ ->filter({_, nl -> nl[1] =~ l:pattern})
    " echomsg "groups: " .. string(groups)
    if empty(groups)
      throw printf("No '%s' group found", pattern)
    endif
    let groups = groups[nb :] + groups[: (nb-1)]
    " echomsg "reordered groups: " .. string(groups)
    let nb = groups[0][0]
  endif
  " The rotation
  let updated_lines = lines[nb :] + lines[: (nb-1)]
  " The update
  call setline(a:fline, updated_lines)
endfunction

command! -range -nargs=* Rotate call s:Rotate(<line1>, <line2>, <f-args>)
```

From there, repeating though a macro (that searches for `%[[[`/`% ]]]`) should be quite easy.

NB: While this solution is definitively overkill (compared to `:move` approach from Romain's answer), this is the simpler one I see where we could handle `\item` entries spanning on several lines.

Comment: Wow, this is quite a lot to digest... I will study it. Yet, my aim is a little bit different (see my comment @romainl )

Comment: That's where the macro (& Vivian's answer) come in: `qr/% \[\[\[/+1<cr>V/% \]\]\]/-1<cr>:Rotate \item<cr>q` (where `<cr>` is you hitting enter/Return) and there, you have your `@r`

Comment: Or more exactly as it seems `V` doesn't work as I remembered in this context: `let @r = '/% \[\[\[/+1'.."\<cr>"..'m</% \]\]\]/-1'.."\<cr>"..'m>:''<,''>Rotate \item'."\<cr>"`

Comment: You helped me to save @Vivian's answer in a register and your answer is also good food for thought. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another `:move` version (from the line to be fixed):

```
:move /% ]]]/-
```

(assuming `% [[[`/`% ]]]` delimits the block`).

We can apply this to all the lines after `% [[[` with

```
:global/\V% [[[/+move /% ]]]/-
```

where we use `:global` to select all the `% [[[` lines (but we don't want to escape `[` in the pattern, so `\V`) and then run `:+move …` (moving the line *after* the match).